# Angular 7 - AuthGuard not working when refresh browser

Tags: angular, angular-services, auth-guard

I am facing an issue with AuthGaurd of a MEAN stack application. AuthGaurd `canActivate` works fine when I navigate through page link. But when refresh page - the page is not working(stay loading state for infinite time)

Here is AuthGuard implementation -

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platform: any, private router: Router, private logInService: LoginService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
            if (this.logInService.loggedIn && !this.logInService.isTokenExpired(this.logInService.getToken())) {
                return true;
            }

            this.router.navigate(['/user/login']);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my login service which is working fine as well -

```
public get loggedIn(): boolean {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
      return (localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_NAME) !== null);
    }
  }

isTokenExpired(token?: string): boolean {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
      if(!token) token = this.getToken();
      if(!token) return true;

      const date = this.getTokenExpirationDate(token);
      if(date === undefined) return false;
      return !(date.valueOf() > new Date().valueOf());  
    }
  }

getTokenExpirationDate(token: string): Date {
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

    if (decoded.exp === undefined) return null;

    const date = new Date(0);
    date.setUTCSeconds(decoded.exp);
    return date;
  }
```

I can't figure out the issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any errors?

I guess that the problem should be that you don't handle was happens if

`if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform))` returns false.

Comment: I need to check it to browser, from server side it would return false